# path error ("can't open","no such file or direcory ") while using openssl command

Tags: openssl, apache2, self-signed

```
Can't open textFile.txt for reading, No such file or directory
25769902144:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('~/correct/path/cakey.key','r')
25769902144:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
error in aes-256-ecb
```

the above error occured when i was trying to sign a certificate request with the following openssl command

$ `openssl ca -config caopenssl.cnf -extensions v3_intermediaire_ca -days 3650 -notext  -in ca_intermediary.csr -out ca_intermediarycert.cert`

i expected a `Signature ok`

to resolve the incident i tried the following:
1- i made sure it was the right path by copying the path returned in the error and by doing `cat` on 2- it. i tried to execute the openssl command with `sudo`,
3-  also did `chmod 777` to change the privatekey file authorized to maximum.

and still,the incident persists!

Comment: Post the contents of `caopenssl.cnf`.

Answer (score 0):

in openssl.cnf file at `[ default ]` section (default location /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf).

i had something like this
`$dir = ~/ca`
i changed it to
`$dir = /home/username/ca`

by deduction:The path seems to be correct but it is not!

my interpretation is that:
this value "`~/ca`" changes depending on the processus trying to read the files
while `/home/username/ca` stay the same no matter the processus calling it. as it is an absolute path.

so i recommand to avoid relative paths.

if this is usefull please rate it.

Comment: "if this is usefull please rate it." Not useful, because your question is offtopic here as unrelated to programming.